# C# Nested List not adding a new list

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, nested

The first List `AStore` iterates and creates a new list for each iteration. The second List `APages` iterates, but does not create a new list on each iteration. I have the same placement for each list creation and List.Add. What is wrong here?

```
public void Promos()
{
    //get store info and id
    var storeinfo = new HtmlWeb();
    var storeshtm = storeinfo.Load(@"Stores.htm");
    var nodes = storeshtm.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("div");
    List<Store> AStore = new List<Store>();
    nodes = nodes[0].ChildNodes;
    int a = 0;
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Name != "#text")
        {
            AStore.Add(new Store(
                node.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].Attributes[7].Value,//storewebid
                "Astore",//storename
                node.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[3].InnerText,//storeaddress
                node.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[5].InnerText,//storecity
                node.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[5].InnerText,//storestate
                node.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[5].InnerText,//storezip
                node.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[7].InnerText,//storephone
                ""//storehours
            ));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
    {
        var circualr = new HtmlWeb();
        var storehtm = circualr.Load(@"http://storewebsite/" + AStore[i].StoreWebID);
        var cnodes = storehtm.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id="+'"'+"Wrapper"+'"'+"]");
        List<Pages> APages = new List<Pages>();
        foreach (var cnode in cnodes)
            if(cnode.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[5].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[1].Name == "a")
                APages.Add(new Pages(cnode.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[5].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[1].Attributes[2].Value));//get inner page links
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the same placement for each list creation

You do **NOT** have the same placement of creation, the `AStore` is created outside of the for loop, and the `APages` one is.